# Construct public ipv6 adress from hostname of router and interface id of client

Tags: ssh, ipv6, hostname

I'm trying to ssh to some client behind a router that has a dynamic IPv6 address.

Directly using the public IPv6 address of the client works just fine.

Now, I'd like to dynamically construct the IPv6 address based on the hostname of the router and the IPv6 interface id of my client.

For example, let `2001:db8::` be my public prefix and the hostname's  (`example.com`) ip be `2001:db8::1319:8a2e:0370:7347`. Then, from the hostname I can find the current public prefix `2001:db8::` and together with the known IPv6 interface ID `::1319:8a2e:0370:7342` of my client I can build the public IPv6 address `2001:db8::1319:8a2e:0370:7342` even if the prefix changed in the meantime.

Is there a syntax for achieving that directly without some kind of external script?

Comment: So you want to take the hostname of the router, get the IP for that hostname, grab probably the ::/64 and then apply the clients local part?
Otherwise clarify in you question what you mean by "IPv6 interface id" and please use at least examples 2001:db8:: is available for documentation/examples

Comment: Business networks are assigned fixed IPv6 prefixes. This is for a residential network where the IPv6 addressing changes to help prevent a ToS violation of running services to the public Internet from a residential network,

Comment: @NiKiZe Yeah, that's what I want. I also added an example.

Comment: There is no standard here, you are making assumptions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Business class internet service should be providing a static IPv6 prefix. The address space is easily big enough to provide this for everyone.

DNS is the first choice for resolving names to IPs. Consider a DNS updating script, running on a box that knows the prefix. nsupdate, ddclient, something like that. A script to drive that is fairly simple: concatenate a /64 prefix plus interface ID.

Maybe store the prefix in DNS as well, so it can be retrieved by name.